# predicate logic conversion

Tags: predicate-logic

I am a novice in learning the conversion of english sentences to predicate logic.I can not convert these sentences into predicate logic.

1.Sue eats everything Bill eats.

2.Nazrul is a national poet.

3.CUET is an engineering university.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, at least your thoughts, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: 2. is quite "trivial"; the only way to symbolize it is : $National-poet(Nazrul)$.

Comment: 1. is a littele bit more "challenging" : re-phrase it as : "for all $x$, if Bill eats $x$, then Sue eats $x$" and then symbolize it...